# How to list out entry types in a section

Tags: entry-type

Something like `craft.entrytypes.section('sectionHandle')` and then loop through them to list out their names.  I'm looking through the docs and can't see how to do this with just the `craft.entries` code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the sections documentation: https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.sections

The following code lists all entrytypes of all sections.

```
{% set sections = craft.sections.getAllSections() %}

{% for section in sections %}

    <h2>{{ section.name }}</h2>

    {% set entryTypes = section.getEntryTypes() %}
    <ul>
        {% for entryType in entryTypes %}

            <li>{{ entryType.name }}</li>

        {% endfor %}

    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

If you like only to show used entry types:

- Loop trough all entries
- Collect all entry types in a array
- Now, you can loop trough the entry types array