# How to get a list of entry types for a section using GraphQL?

Tags: sections, entry-type, graphql, craft4

The goal is to get a list of entry types for a section, so that a user can filter entires by entry type e.g.

```
query Entries {
  entries(section: "content", type: ["news", "article", "video"]) {
    id
    title
    .............
  }
}
```

I know this can be done template side using [getEntryTypes()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-models-section.html#public-methods) as per this question - [How to list out entry types in a section](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14759/how-to-list-out-entry-types-in-a-section)

However I'm not sure how to do this with GraphQL, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can query for elements (entries, users, etc.) using Craft's GraphQL API, but not for collections of elements (sections, user groups, etc.).

My suggestion would be to either hard-code these, as I assume they won't change very often, or create a custom API endpoint using a custom module/plugin. See this article for a starting point:
https://putyourlightson.com/articles/building-a-restful-api-in-craft-cms