# Adding section to Graphql "View - Public Schema" programatically

Tags: plugin-development, graphql

So, I am creating new section called "My Section" with handle "mySection" via plugin. All good there.

I want to be able for my section to be Viewable via Public Schema each time it is created (when plugin is installed / enabled).

I cannot figure out how to add my section inside Viewable Public Schema using Gql in plugin.

Anyone has any idea or snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query for elements (entries, users, etc.) using Craft's GraphQL API, but not for collections of elements (sections, user groups, etc.).

I already answered a very similar question, see https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/39709/180